# Find and replace term

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, replace

In my app, I used to have a property called 'xyz'. I had variants of xyz called xyz1, xyz2, xyz3, etc. In my code, there was a part where I set all their values to be identical like this:

```
[xyz setProperty:@"value"];
[xyz2 setProperty:@"value"];
...
[xyz90 setProperty:@"value"];
```

I now optimized my code a whole lot, but need to get rid of this redundancy. How can I search for everything that contains "`[xyz setProperty:@"value"];`", but also delete the variants of xyz using the find and replace function of xcode? I tried putting what is in double quotes above, but it only finds the first one, and I have many. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from the find bar. Do control-f to open the bar, then do this:

1. type [xyz setProperty:@"value"]; or copy and paste it from your code
2. put the cursor to the right of the z
3. click on the magnifying glass to the left of your text
4. choose "Insert Pattern", and choose "Any Characters"
5. Go to the magnifying glass again and choose "Edit Find Options", and choose "Regular Expression" from the "Matching Style" pull down (it should now find all the versions where you have one or more numbers after xyz).
6. To also match the xyz ones with no numbers, change (.+?) to (.*)